Anchor behavior when using href linking to datauri on Visualforce vs Lightning
I am having issues with using dataUri on Visualforce pages. I am setting up an anchor link with a href to a JSON dataUri that looks like this:
<a class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" download="test.json" href="data:application/json;base64,{base64string}">Download</a>
My desired behavior is to have a button like object that when you click it will automatically download the encoded JSON. In a lightning page such as in a lwc deployed to an accounts page for example this works exactly as expected across all browsers.
However in Visualforce the behavior is completely different. When  the link is clicked it is opened as a popup in a new tab that gets blocked on Chromium based browsers and works on Firefox.
Adding target="_blank" allows for the correct behavior on Chromium browsers but on Firefox this ends up getting blocked by CSP.
My questions are what is causing these differences in behavior and is it possible to have it work as it does in lwc but in Visualforce so I can download this JSON in both browsers just by clicking the anchor?
